# Error processing SQL: could not prepare statement (1 1 values for 15 columns)

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite

I am trying to develop a phonegap app.I am trying to fetch the JSON data from an URL and storing it into SQLite db. When I am doing so, I got an error:

> Error processing SQL: could not prepare statement (1 1 values for 15
>   columns)

My code is as follow.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var db,did;
            function loaddb()
            {
                db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }
            function createDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERIDDETAILS');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERIDDETAILS (deviceid TEXT NOT NULL)');
            }
            function errorCB(err) {
                //alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
                console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
            }
            function successCB() {
                console.log("success");
            }
            function insertDB(tx) {
                did = $("[name='deviceid']").val();
                var sql='INSERT INTO USERIDDETAILS(deviceid)VALUES(?)';
                tx.executeSql(sql,[did],sucessQueryDB,errorCB);
                console.log(did);
            }   
            function sucessQueryDB(tx){
                alert("selected");
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS',[],renderList,errorCB); 
            }
            function renderList(tx,results){ 
            alert("rendering");
                var htmlstring='';
                var len=results.rows.length;
                alert("rendered called"+ len);
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    htmlstring += '<li>'+ results.rows.item(i).deviceid+'</li>';
                }   
                $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
                $('#resultList').listview('refresh');
            }

            function onClick(){
                db.transaction(insertDB,errorCB);
                $.ajax({
                    url : "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=xxxxxxxxx",
                    dataType:"json",
                    cache: false,
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    debugger;
                            alert(xhr.statusText);
                            alert(thrownError.code);
                        },
                    success : function(json) {
                    console.log("Entering getIdList.success()");
                    console.log(json);
                    alert(json);
                    if (json.length == 0) {
                        window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
                    } else {
                        var obj, des , md ,apiKeys;
                        //i=channels object length
                        for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
                            obj = json[i];
                            //console.log(obj);
                            if (obj == null || obj == "") {
                                window.alert("\n The "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                            } else {
                                if (obj.id == did) {

                                if (obj.name == null || obj.name == "") {
                                        window.alert("\n The name portion of "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                        alert("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                        dnamedb();                               
                                        dnameForm();

                                        var name = obj.name;
                                        console.log(name);
                                        function dnamedb(){
                                            db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                            db.transaction(creatednDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                            alert("dname");
                                        }
                                        function creatednDB(tx) {
                                            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEVICENAME');
                                            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEVICENAME(Dname TEXT NOT NULL)');
                                            alert("done");
                                        }

                                        function insertdnDB(tx){
                                            var sql = "INSERT INTO DEVICENAME(Dname) VALUES ('"+name+"')";
                                            tx.executeSql(sql);
                                            console.log(name);
                                        }

                                        function dnameForm(){
                                            db.transaction(insertdnDB,errorCB);
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }

                                if (obj.description == null || obj.description == "") {
                                    window.alert("\n The description portion of "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                } else {
                                    des = JSON.parse("{" + obj.description + "}");
                                    console.log("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nName : " + des.n + "\nEmailid : " + des.e + "\nMobile : " + des.m + "\nAddress-1 : " + des.a1 + "\nAddress-2 : " + des.a2+ "\nSumpheight : " + des.sh+ "\nSumplength : " + des.sl+ "\nSumpwidth : " + des.sw+ "\nSumpcapacity : " + des.sc+"\nTanklength : " + des.tl+ "\nTankwidth : " + des.tw+ "\nTankheight : " + des.th+ "\nTankdensity : " + des.td+ "\nTankcapacity : " + des.tc+ "\nMotorpower : " + des.mp);
                                    loaduddb();
                                    userdetForm();

                                    function loaduddb()
                                    {
                                        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                        db.transaction(createudDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                        console.log("kkkk");
                                    }
                                    function createudDB(tx) {
                                        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERDETAILS');
                                        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERDETAILS(Name TEXT NOT NULL,Emailid TEXT NOT NULL,Mobile INTEGER NOT NULL,Address1 TEXT NOT NULL,Address2 TEXT NOT NULL,Sumpheight INTEGER NOT NULL,Sumplength INTEGER NOT NULL,Sumpwidth INTEGER NOT NULL,Sumpcapacity INTEGER NOT NULL,Tanklength INTEGER NOT NULL,Tankwidth INTEGER NOT NULL,Tankheight INTEGER NOT NULL,Tankdensity INTEGER NOT NULL,Tankcapacity INTEGER NOT NULL,Motorpower INTEGER NOT NULL)');
                                        console.log("done ud");
                                    }

                                    function insertudDB(tx){
                                        var sql = "INSERT INTO USERDETAILS(Name,Emailid,Mobile,Address1,Address2,Sumpheight,Sumplength,Sumpwidth,Sumpcapacity,Tanklength,Tankwidth,Tankheight,Tankdensity,Tankcapacity,Motorpower) VALUES ('"+ des.n + '","' + des.e + '","' + des.m + '","' + des.a1 + '","' + des.a2+ '","' + des.sh+ '", "' + des.sl+ '","' + des.sw+ '","' + des.sc+ '","' + des.tl+ '","' + des.tw+ '","' + des.th+ '","' + des.td+ '","' + des.tc+ '","' + des.mp + "')";
                                        tx.executeSql(sql);
                                        console.log(des.n,des.e,des.m,des.a1,des.a2,des.sh,des.sl,des.sw,des.sc,des.tl,des.tw,des.th,des.td,des.tc,des.mp);

                                    }
                                    function userdetForm(){
                                        db.transaction(insertudDB,errorCB);
                                        return false;

                                    }

                                }

                                if (obj.metadata == null || obj.metadata == "") {
                                    window.alert("\n The metadata portion of "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                } else {
                                    md = JSON.parse("{" + obj.metadata + "}");
                                    console.log("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nTankno : " + md.tn + "\nTankano : " + md.ta + "\nTankeid : " + md.te + "\nCleanerno : " + md.cn + "\nCleanerano : " + md.ca + "\nCleanereid : " + md.ce+"\nPno : " + md.pn+ "\nPano : " + md.pa+ "\nPeid : " + md.pe+ "\nEno : " + md.en +"\nEano : " + md.ea +"\nEeid : " + md.ee +"\nMno : " + md.mn +"\nMano : " + md.ma +"\nMeid : " + md.me +"\nMm : " + md.mm +"\nMmdl : " + md.mmdl +"\nMmfd : " + md.mmfd +"\nMprd : " + md.mprd);
                                    loadmddb();
                                    metadataForm();
                                    function loadmddb()
                                    {
                                        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                        db.transaction(createmdDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                        console.log("md loaded");
                                    }
                                    function createmdDB(tx) {
                                        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS METADATA');
                                        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS METADATA(Tankno INTEGER NOT NULL,Tankano INTEGER NOT NULL,Tankeid TEXT NOT NULL,Cleanerno INTEGER NOT NULL,Cleanerano INTEGER NOT NULL,Cleanereid TEXT NOT NULL,Pno INTEGER NOT NULL,Pano INTEGER NOT NULL,Peid TEXT NOT NULL,Eno INTEGER NOT NULL,Eano INTEGER NOT NULL,Eeid TEXT NOT NULL,Mno INTEGER NOT NULL,Mano INTEGER NOT NULL,Meid TEXT NOT NULL,Mm INTEGER NOT NULL,Mmdl INTEGER NOT NULL,Mmfd INTEGER NOT NULL,Mprd INTEGER NOT NULL)');
                                        console.log(" md done");
                                    }

                                    function insertmdDB(tx){
                                    var sql = "INSERT INTO METADATA(Tankno,Tankano,Tankeid,Cleanerno,Cleanerano,Cleanereid,Pno,Pano,Peid,Eno,Eano,Eeid,Mno,Mano,Meid,Mm,Mmdl,Mmfd,Mprd) VALUES ('" +md.tn+ '","' +md.ta+ '","' +md.te+ '","' +md.cn+ '","' +md.ca+ '" ,"' +md.ce+ '","' +md.pn+ '","' +md.pa+ '","' +md.pe+ '","' +md.en+ '","' +md.ea+ '","' +md.ee+ '","' +md.mn+ '","' +md.ma+ '","' +md.me+ '","' +md.mm+ '","' +md.mmdl+ '","' +md.mmfd+ '","' +md.mprd+"')";
                                        tx.executeSql(sql);
                                        console.log(md.tn,md.ta,md.te,md.cn,md.ca,md.ce,md.pn,md.pa,md.pe,md.en,md.ea,md.ee,md.mn,md.ma,md.me, md.mm,md.mmdl,md.mmfd,md.mprd);
                                    }

                                    function metadataForm(){
                                        db.transaction(insertmdDB,errorCB);
                                        return false;

                                    }
                                }   

                                if (obj.api_keys == null || obj.api_keys.length == 0) {
                                    window.alert("\n The api_keys portion of "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                } else {
                                    apiKeys = obj.api_keys;
                                    //j=channel apikey length
                                    for (var j = 1; j < apiKeys.length; j++) {
                                    console.log("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nApikey : " + apiKeys[j].api_key + "\nWriteflag:" + apiKeys[j].write_flag);
                                    loadakdb();
                                    apikeyForm();

                                    var apikey = apiKeys[j].api_key;
                                    console.log(apikey);
                                    var writeflag = apiKeys[j].write_flag;
                                    console.log(writeflag);
                                    function loadakdb()
                                    {
                                        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                        db.transaction(createakDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                        console.log("ak loaded");
                                    }
                                    function createakDB(tx) {
                                        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS APIKEYS');
                                        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS APIKEYS(Apikey TEXT NOT NULL,Writeflag TEXT NOT NULL)');
                                        console.log("ak done");
                                    }

                                    function insertakDB(tx){
                                        var sql = "INSERT INTO APIKEYS(Apikey,Writeflag) VALUES ('" +apikey+ '","' +writeflag+ "')";
                                        tx.executeSql(sql);
                                        console.log(apikey,writeflag);
                                    }

                                    function apikeyForm(){
                                        db.transaction(insertakDB,errorCB);
                                        return false;

                                    }
                                    }
                                    }
                                $.ajax({
                                    url : "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/"+did+"/feeds.json?api_key="+apikey,
                                      dataType: "json",
                                      cache: false,
                                      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                        debugger;
                                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                                        alert(thrownError);
                                      },
                                      success: function(json1) {
                                      console.log(json1);

                                        json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed,i){
                                          console.log("\n The details of " + i + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at
                                          + "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2+"\nField3:" + feed.field3);      
                                            feedsdb();
                                            feedsForm();

                                        function feedsdb()
                                            {
                                                db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                                db.transaction(createcfDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                                console.log("feeds load");
                                            }
                                            function createcfDB(tx) {
                                                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FEEDS');
                                                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FEEDS(Created_at TEXT NOT NULL,Entry_id, TEXT NOT NULL,Field1 INTEGER NOT NULL,Field2 INTEGER NOT NULL,Field3 INTEGER NOT NULL )');
                                                //console.log("feeds done");
                                            }

                                            function insertcfDB(tx){ 
                                                var sql = "INSERT INTO FEEDS(Created_at,Entry_id,Field1,Field2,Field3) VALUES ('" +feed.created_at+ '","' +feed.entry_id+ '","' +feed.field1+ '","' +feed.field2+ '","' +feed.field3+ "')";
                                                tx.executeSql(sql);
                                                console.log(feed.created_at,feed.entry_id,feed.field1,feed.field2,feed.field3);
                                                db.transaction(sucessfeedsDB,errorCB);
                                            }
                                            function sucessfeedsDB(tx){
                                                alert("selected");
                                                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM FEEDS',[],renderList1,errorCB);    
                                            }
                                            function renderList1(tx,results){ 
                                                alert("rendering");
                                                var htmlstring='';
                                                var len=results.rows.length;
                                                alert("rendered called"+ len);
                                                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                                                    htmlstring += '<li>'+ results.rows.item(i).feed.created_at+'<br>'+results.rows.item(i).feed.entry_id+'<br>'+results.rows.item(i).feed.field1+'<br>'+results.rows.item(i).feed.field2+'<br>'+results.rows.item(i).feed.field3+'</li>';
                                                }   
                                                $('#resultFeed').html(htmlstring);
                                                $('#resultFeed').listview('refresh');
                                            }
                                            function feedsForm(){
                                                db.transaction(insertcfDB,errorCB);
                                                return false;
                                            }

                                        }); 

                                      }
                                    });
                                }                   
                            }           
                        }
                    }   
                }
            });                         
            window.open("new4.html");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>   
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3> Login </h3>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            loaddb();
            }); 
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <form id="myForm">
             <br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid" placeholder="DeviceId"><br>
             <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return onClick()">
        </form>

    </div>
```

In the above code i got error from description part i.e., function loaduddb().It is inserting the values and throwing the error as above and the same error is continued for `metadata(function loadmddb())`, `apikeys(function loadakdb())` and `feeds(function feedsdb())` section as well.Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue..Thankyou

Comment: you should organize your db functions better. Why are you defining them in your ajax? this is bad copy and paste. You've already define the same functions above it. You should initialize them ondeviceready. docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_eve…

Comment: The link you have referred is doesnt exit can you send the right one @Mistergreen

Comment: I am fetching the data from the ajax url and storing in the db...so i have defined it in ajax@Mistergreen